# FreeBSd rc.d source another file

Tags: shell, freebsd, built-in, startupscript

On startup I manually run `source /usr/local/etc/credentials.sh`.

I've made a script `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/load_credentials` to run command for me at start-up. However the script does not succeed:

```
$ /usr/local/etc/rc.d/load_credentials start
eval: source: not found
```

#### `load_credentials`

The script is based on the example in [rc-scripting](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/articles/rc-scripting/) docs.

```
#!/bin/sh 

. /etc/rc.subr 

name="load_credentials" 
start_cmd="${name}_start" 
stop_cmd=":" 

load_credentials_start() 
{
    source /usr/local/etc/psql_creds.sh
}

load_rc_config $name 
run_rc_command "$1"
```

#### `credentials.sh`

```
export DB_USER="JimmyJohn"
export DB_PASS="password123"
```

##### EDITs

Moved files as advised by [@Michael-O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696632/michael-o)

Comment: /etc/rc.d is for the base system only. Don't touch it. Move your file to /usr/local/etc/rc.d and your cred file to /usr/local/etc/{name}.conf or similar

Comment: `source` is a built-in of `bash`. The RC scripts run under `/bin/sh`. Use `.` instead of `source`.

Comment: @RichardSmith  Thank you! The script no longer crashes. However, there's simply no output and the variables inside of credential.sh have not been sourced. For example: `echo $DB_USER` returns nothing.

Comment: Are you expecting these credentials to be available to your login shell? Look at the manual page for your preferred shell for its list of startup files. For example, for `bash` you can use `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @RichardSmith will the credentials be available for crontasks running from my user?

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny probably not. Your cron tasks do not run under your login shell. They are run by the cron daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment

> will the credentials be available for crontasks running from my user?

it would seem you wish this to work in crontasks.

Here is a sample cronjob that I tested working and it does indeed work in crontasks.

Make a file in /usr/local/bin/crondo.sh

```
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/crondo.sh
# cat /usr/local/bin/crondo.sh
#!/bin/sh
. /usr/local/etc/psql_creds.sh
echo $DB_USER
```

Add this line to crontab with `crontab -e`

```
# Run 22 minutes after every hour.
22      *       *       *       *       /usr/local/bin/crondo.sh > /tmp/out
```